# vue js - How use vue 3 component in vue 2 app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I need a fast way that will allow me to use vue 3 component in vue 2. Right now, I don't care about performance and speed. A solution that uses both vue 3 and vue 2 will work. I wanted to do it through web components, but vue 3 does not allow them yet
I have a chat module on vue 3 that I want to integrate into vue 2. Do you have a quick way to do this?

Comment: could you update your vue 2 project to vue 3?

Answer (score -1):

If your component is written in option-api you can integrate it in a Vue 2 project. Just watch out for some [breaking changes](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#breaking-changes), but I think it's unlikely to encounter such edge cases.